# Is it feasible and rational to combine the Tails package and Whonix package to improve the anonymity of the client? And, how to implement it?

Tags: anonymity, configuration, security, tails, whonix

Is it feasible and rational to combine the capability of Tails package and Whonix package to improve the anonymity and security of the client? And if so, how one may implement it?

Comment: @Linostar is right. As an addendum, let me say, it's both rational and feasible. Quote: `And if so, how one may implement it?` from a user or developer perspective?

Comment: @adrelanos, I feel the developer should have priority over the user. Meaning if developer do not implement it first, very few users if any even try to think about that.

Comment: Ok, as a dev... In a nutshell... Look around in Whonix's code base. Optional, maybe read the [source code introduction](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Dev/Source_Code_Intro). Then implement a build step that runs at the end, that creates a Live DVD. Perhaps using Debian's live-build package. Install a virtualizer. Install the whonix-host-additions package inside. Import the virtual machines. Get in contact with the developers to merge your work into the mainline. Ideally, provide maintenance / support for others. All it needs is self-initiative.

Comment: @adrelanos Ok, Would you please make an answer out of this, I will give you an upvote to express my appreciation. Warm Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have first to define what are your anonymity and security needs, and see if either solution can provide it on its own. Both solutions have different goals and different threat models as [summarized by whonix maintainer here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68385/design-differences-of-tails-and-whonix-concerning-virtualization/68387#68387). The main feature in Tails that Whonix lacks is **amnesic capability**, which is making your device forgets everything that happens and leaving no trace about what you were doing in Tails. That function can be alleviated to a point by using a full disk encryption under Whonix.

To this day, no one has implemented or developed a tool that combines both Whonix and Tails.